# Derived pullback of the coarse moduli morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, algebraic-stacks, derived-functors

Let $f: \mathcal{X}\to X$ be a morphism from a smooth DM-stack $\mathcal{X}$ to its coarse moduli space $X$. Assume that $X$ is also smooth. Is it true that $Lf^*$ is fully faithful and induces an equivalence of $D^b(coh(X))$ with an admissible subcategory of $D^b(coh(\mathcal{X}))$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If both $\mathcal{X}$ and $X$ are locally Noetherian and regular, then $f$ is flat.  Then $Lf^*$ is the usual pullback $f^*$.  If $\mathcal{X}$ is tame, then the natural transformation $$\theta:\text{Id} \Rightarrow f_*f^*,$$ is a natural isomorphism.  However, when $\mathcal{X}$ is not tame, this can fail.  For instance, let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$, let $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})_k$ denote the usual finite, étale $k$-group scheme whose underlying group of $k$-points is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and consider the Artin-Schreier action,
$$
\mu:(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})_k\times_k \mathbb{P}^1_k \to \mathbb{P}^1_k, \ a\cdot[s,t] = [s+at,t].
$$
Let $q:\mathbb{P}^1_k \to \mathcal{X}$ be the associated quotient stack, which is a smooth Deligne-Mumford stack. 
Consider the $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})_k$-invariant $k$-morphism,
$$
F:\mathbb{P}^1_k \to \mathbb{P}^1_k, \ F([s,t]) = [s^p-st^{p-1},t^p].
$$
This is the uniform categorical quotient in the category of $k$-schemes.  Denote the target by $X$.
Thus $F$ factors through a $1$-morphism of stacks,
$$
f:\mathcal{X} \to X,
$$
and this is a coarse moduli space of $\mathcal{X}$.  But now consider the fiber over the closed point $\infty = [1,0]$ in $X$.  The scheme-theoretic fiber of $F$ is the closed subscheme $$Z(t^p) \cong \text{Spec}\ k[(t/s)]/\langle (t/s)^p \rangle.$$  Moreover, the induced action of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})_k$ on $Z(t^p)$ by $k$-morphisms is
$$
\mu_\infty: (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})_k \times_k \text{Spec}\ k[(t/s)]/\langle (t/s)^p \rangle \to \text{Spec}\ k[(t/s)]/\langle (t/s)^p \rangle,$$
$$ \mu_\infty(a)^*(t/s) = (t/s)/(1+a(t/s)) = (t/s)(1-a(t/s)+a^2(t/s)^2 + \dots + (-a)^{p-2}(t/s)^{p-2}),
$$
for every $a\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \subset k$.
In particular, the $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-invariant $k$-subspace of $k[(t/s)]/\langle (t/s)^p \rangle$ is spanned by $1$ and $(t/s)^{p-1}$.  Since the invariant subspace is not $1$-dimensional, for the skyscraper sheaf $\kappa(\infty)$ on $X$ supported at $\infty$, the natural transformation 
$$
\theta_{\kappa(\infty)} : \kappa(\infty) \to f_*f^*\kappa(\infty),
$$
is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jason, but could you explain, please, why $f$ is flat and $\theta: Id\to Rf_{*}f^*$ is isomorphism in the tame case?

Comment: First of all, in the tame case, $Rf_*$ equals $f_*$.  In the non-tame case, $Rf_*$ does not even map $D^b$ to $D^b$.

Comment: Flatness of $f$ is a corollary of the local flatness criterion, cf. Theorem 23.1, p. 179 of H. Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*, Cambridge U. Press.  However, via the Chevalley-Shephard-Todd theorem, your hypotheses are extremely strong.

Comment: Both exactness of $f_*$ and $\theta$ being isomorphic can be checked etale locally on $X$.  Thus, assume that $\mathcal{X}$ is $[Y/G]$ with induced map $F:Y\to X$ and $|G|$ prime to the characteristic.  Then $f_*f^*$ is the same as $(F_*F^*(-))^G$.  Since $F$ is finite (hence affine), $F_*$ is exact.  Since $|G|$ is prime to the characteristic $(-)^G$ is exact.  Thus $f_*$ is exact.  Because $f_*$ is exact, to check $\theta$ is isomorphic, it suffices to consider $\theta_{\mathcal{O}}$.  This case follows from the definition of the categorical quotient of $Y$ by $G$.